# Xpath Get href inside attribute

Tags: xpath, href

I would like to know how can I write xpath to get what is inside href quotes here :

```
<a rel="test" href="/tf-265-exemple">mountain</a>
```

I tried xpath : `//a[@rel='test']/@href`
but not working so much

Regards

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
'string(//a[@rel="test"]/@href)'
```